# How to pass the values (Data) from database travez JSON. ASSEMBLE THE JSON - Highcharts

Tags: javascript, linq, highcharts, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5

This is Highcharts javascript, I need to pass the values (I guess by JSON) categories and variables Series.
I could use some help how to do it, maybe by example?

**This is my code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var seriesData = ' ';
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/Analytics/GetDataAsJsonMax/',

    error: function () {
        alert("An error occurred.");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        seriesData = data;// [data];// or [data]
        bindChart(seriesData);

    }

});




  function bindChart(seriesData) {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun','Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°Cgr'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        //series: [{
        //    name: 'Tokyo',
        //    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        //        }]
        series: seriesData
    });
};
```

**My method in the controller would look like:**

```
public JsonResult GetDataAsJsonMax()
    {
        var allData = (from p in db.Pedidos.Include("Localidad")
                       group p by p.Localidad.Nombre into pedGrupo
                       select new
                       {
                           name = pedGrupo.Key,
                           data = pedGrupo.Count()
                       });

        var OrderData = allData.ToList();
        return Json(OrderData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**This returns the method:**

```
[{"name":"CACUI ,EST","data":2},{"name":"EL CAJON","data":3}]
```

**[image: so it looks in the browser:]**

Comment: Pass them from where? Your server? LINQ is basically a DSL, not a place. Generally, it's a good idea to setup a REST endpoint that serves up your data is JSON format.

Comment: Exactly, my idea is to create a method in the controller where I return a JSON using a LINQ query, but not that way back to receive the JSON in javascript.

Comment: Read up on [AJAX.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) Since you're using jQuery, [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) will be helpful.

Comment: *This is my code* - What's wrong with it? In other words: where *exactly* do you need help?

Comment: What I need is to load the series: [{" "}] according to the JSON returned in GetDataAsJson (), ie, make it dynamic. I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Have  you seen Highchart docs? http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-intro

Comment: Your data cannot be presented as series, based on the result you are getting, it should be presented as Bars, since its returning `[{name,data with one value}]`, here a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-basic/)

Comment: @HadiHassan Of course, you understand that the problem is not that just like sending the series.
For example I think LINQ query and the achievement to return my name (I use as Key), and the data always returns a value me (not a number: |).
Maybe not as generate the query, my idea would be something like amount of sales by date grouped by location.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński I'm just using this model but I managed to generate the JSON data

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/)

Comment: any ideas please? Thank you.

Comment: Any help please? Thank you